# getting the prompt to recognize the letters in a javascript hangman games "chosen word"

Tags: javascript, prompt

so i am trying to teach myself javascript and have decided to try and make a basic hangman game, as it seems to be a popular interview/test question. My plan is to use Math.random to pick a select word out of a pool of words, and then use the prompt feature to find the letters of the word. Unfortunately, I have been unable to figure out how to get the prompt to recognize my input. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var secretWords = ["batman", "Donkey kong", "ninja", "programming"];
var chosenWord = secretWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * secretWords.length)];
var guesses = 8;
var letters = chosenWord.length
var guess = prompt("GUESS A LETTER");


alert(chosenWord);

for (var i = 0; i <= letters; i++) {
  letters[i] = chosenWord.substring(i, i++)
}
if (guess = i) {
  alert("nice")
} else {
  alert("Wrong");
}
```

Comment: For one, `guess = i` will set `guess` to `i`, not compare it. You want `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 0):

i is your loop variable. It will always be equal to the value of letters when the loop is finished looping. That is not what you want to  compare against. Instead, compare as you loop through the letters.

```
var secretWords = ["batman", "Donkey kong", "ninja", "programming"];
var chosenWord = secretWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*secretWords.length)];
var guesses = 8;
var letters = chosenWord.length
var guess = prompt("GUESS A LETTER");    

var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < letters; i++){
    if (guess == chosenWord.substring(i, i + 1))
        found = true;
}
if (found) {
    alert("Nice")
}
else {
    alert("Wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are looping from `0` to, and with, the length of the chosen word. I assume that you try to check if the letter given is in the word that is selected, but the logic is unfortunately off.

To check if a string contains a letter, or part of a word, you can use the [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method. Every string has this method and with it you can check if the given string is included in your string that compare it with. It will then return true or false based on if the string is included or not. For example:

```
var example = 'hello';
example.includes('h'); // true
example.includes('i'); // false
```

JavaScript is case sensitive. So in order for your game to work and make the user input ambiguous about uppercase or lowercase characters, make sure to make all your `secretWords` in either lowercase or uppercase, depending on your choice. Then when the user provides input, change the input to, again, either uppercase or lowercase with the [`String.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) methods.

```js
var secretWords = ["batman", "donkey kong", "ninja", "programming"];
var chosenWord = secretWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*secretWords.length)];
var guesses = 8;
var letters = chosenWord.length

alert(chosenWord);

var guess = prompt("GUESS A LETTER");
var guessLowerCase = guess.toLowerCase();
var isGuessedLetterInWord = chosenWord.includes(guessLowerCase);

if (isGuessedLetterInWord) {
  alert('nice');
} else {
  alert('wrong');
}
```